# What motorcycle has brake rotor with bolts pattern of 4x55mm?

Tags: motorcycle, brakes, brake-rotor

I just bought a rear rim for motorcycle but it doesn't have brake rotor. Pattern of mounting bolts is 4 holes (in square) and spacing between holes is 55/56mm (maybe 55.5mm) - square base. And (square) diagonal spacing is ~80mm. Center hole seems to be 58mm.

I'm looking for a disc brake that I can buy to fit that rim.

Any idea what bike has that type of mounting?

Rim is quite small - 13 inches. And I think it is of asian/italian originating brand, but that may be long stretch

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Post a picture of the rim, maybe someone will recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Most rotor manufacturers have a catalogue where you can search with outer diameter, swept area, pcd and thickness.

So, maybe online, but the specialist stores usually do have those catalogues and you can find what you want that way. Done it a few years back for changing from solid to vented, then had to check out calipers and the supports needed.